# Which is the easiest way to combine small HDFS blocks?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I'm collecting logs with Flume to the HDFS. For the test case I have small files (~300kB) because the log collecting process was scaled for the real usage.

Is there any easy way to combine these small files into larger ones which are closer to the HDFS block size (64MB)?

Comment: Do you want to combine files for storage, or for mapreduce job input?

Comment: Is there a way to combine them from a mappers perspective?

Comment: I would like to combine them for storage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GNU coreutils *split* could do the work.

If the source data are lines - in my case they are - and one line is around `84 bytes`, then an HDFS block `64MB` could contain around `800000` lines:

```
hadoop dfs -cat /sourcedir/* | split --lines=800000 - joined_
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal ./joined_* /destdir/
```

or with `--line-bytes` option:

```
hadoop dfs -cat /sourcedir/* | split --line-bytes=67108864 - joined_
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal ./joined_* /destdir/
```

Comment: btw I could imagine a hadoop command to do the same, so if anybody is interested, the question is still open.

Answer (score 3):

My current solution is to write a MapReduce job that effectively does nothing, while having a limited number of reducers. Each reducer outputs a file, so this cats them together. You can add the name of the original file in each line to help show where it came from.

I'm still interested in hearing if there is a standard or proven best way of doing this that I am not aware of.

Comment: This is what I have done.  I use addInputPath in the SequenceFileInputFormat class to add all of the files I wish to 'crush' and then run the job.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at File Crusher open sourced by media6degrees. It might be a little outdated but you can download the source and make your changes and/or contribute. The JAR and Source are in: http://www.jointhegrid.com/hadoop_filecrush/index.jsp

This is essentially a map-reduce technique for merging small files.